# SQL Rails rescue request for non existing user

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, null

I have small problem. Lets say I have `users` 1, 2 and 4. And now I'm trying to use this query:

```
User.select(:channel).where(:id => rand(1..User.count)).first.channel
```

Which in this case works like this:

```
User.select(:channel).where(:id => rand(1..3)).first.channel
```

And well, thats my problem. I can select `user 1` and `user 2`. `User 4` is unreachable. And if it try to take `user 3` it returns me that there is no `.channel` method, because everything is `nil` then... What should I do so it could reach `users` 1, 2, 4 and ignore `user 3` which is `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first get the list of available record IDs and then pick a random id:

```
ids = User.pluck(:id)
User.select(:channel).where(:id => ids.sample).first.channel
```

But of course that requires two queries so if that isn't efficient enough you could try telling the DB itself to select a random record. For example, if you're using MySQL you could so something like this:

```
User.order('rand()').limit(1)
```

Comment: `User.order('rand()').limit(1).first.channel` Works perfect! Thanks! :)